# Proper simulation of [] operator

Tags: c++, operators

Consider the case of Number class containing an array of digits. I want the class user to access the digits easily, so I overload the [] operator, such that user can choose a digit by a power of ten, eg. number[2] is a digit representing hundreds, and so on. The class is index-safe - if user specifies index out of range, 0 is returned (as 10 = 0010).

However, setting a digit requires some more effort, because if exponent exceeds the size of internal table holding the digits, the latter has to be extended.

It is clear, that different approach has to be chosen, whether user wants to retrieve a digit and when he wants to store it. I came up with the following solution (the classes are partial, only to show the idea):

```
class Number;

class Digit
{
    friend class Number;

private:
    Number number;
    int exponent;

    Digit(Number & newNumber, int newExponent) 
        : number(newNumber), exponent(newExponent)
    {
    }

public:
    operator unsigned char() 
    {
        return number.GetDigit(exponent);
    }

    void operator = (unsigned char digit) 
    {
        number.SetDigit(exponent, digit);
    }
};

class Number
{
    friend class Digit;

private:
    unsigned char GetDigit(int exponent) { ... };
    void SetDigit(int exponent, unsigned char value) { ... };

public:
    Digit operator [] (int exponent)
    {
        return Digit(*this, exponent);
    }
}
```

The operators inside Digit class obviously calls some private Number's methods, such that user can assign a value and retrieve one. I also can act differently, whether user wants to retrieve value and when he wants to store it.

There is a problem with const, however. If the Number class instance is const, the operator [] cannot be called unless it is marked as const too. However, then a Digit class cannot be instantiated, because it requires Number &, while const Number & is passed.

One solution involves using a const_cast, but it feels like using a hack - not to mention, that removing the const would allow user to modify the number instance by using Digit's operator =. Is there a way to resolve this problem differently than using const_cast or writing another class, say, ConstDigit?

---

Another problem: I wouldn't like the user to store the instance of Digit, as it is provided only for user's comfort. Private copy constructor prevents user from storing the digit like:

```
auto digit = number[5];
```

However, he still can store the digit by reference:

```
auto digit & = number[5];
```

The number is passed to digit by reference (see the Digit constructor) to prevent problems with pointers, but it won't prevent a AV in this situation:

```
auto number = new Number();
auto & digit = (*number)[5];
delete number;
digit = 12;
```

I may forbid user to use the new operator on Number, but maybe there is another way?

---

A longer answer, why I can't return digits by reference.

The number is held as two separate vectors, one for integer part and one for fraction part (I've simplified the example in question, but it doesn't really matter here). For example,

```
123.456
```

is stored as

```
intPart : {3, 2, 1}
fracPart : {4, 5, 6}
```

If user requests the digit on 100th place, I just check, that it's outside the array bounds and return 0 (because - as I've mentioned, 10 = 0010 = 00010 = ... and so on)

However, if user wishes to set the digit, I have to extend the array to fill all remaining exponents, eg.

```
100 // user wants to set millions' digit to 5
5 [000] 100 // i have to add these empty digits
```

Of course I might do it as well in the [] operator. But if user decides to set 100th digit to 0, I would have to add 98 digits for nothing and I even have no way to check, if he tries to do so (and the number is supposed to be stored in smallest possible representation with neither leading nor trailing zeros present). I have no way to compact the storage after his assignment either.

One of the solutions is, of course, to drop the [] operator and use getter/setter. But the whole point is to make the class easy to use and [] operator fulfills this assumption a lot more than a pair of getter/setter methods :)

Comment: You can have `Number::operator[]()` return `Digit` and `Number::operator[]() const` return `const Digit`. A separate `ConstDigit` class is probably not needed, since you don't modify a digit separately from the number that holds that digit.

Comment: @n.m. Ok, but Digit's constructor requires Number &, while inside Number::operator[]() const I would have to pass const Number &, which is incompatible with Digit's constructor (compiler complains, I've tried it already).

Comment: @JohannesS. Ok, I agree; the getter/setter may be a little less comfortable to use, but the interface will still be more intuitive. That'll eliminate the problems with const and broken references too.

Comment: There's no obligation to have just one constructor.

Comment: Sure, but the number class instance passed by parameter (either const or not) has to be stored in the internal field and we'll come back to the first problem again.

Comment: Oh sorry. My mistake. Always store a non-const pointer. In a const method add constness to it, it's better then removing one ad no cast is needed, just an assignment.

Comment: On a second thought the approach with two separate classes is better. Or rather, the approach with const Digit won't work. You cannot copy a const object while enforcing constness of the copy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll start the answer with your second problem: If you take references, you have to make sure that it is still valid when you want to access it. In your example, this is definitely not the case. I see the point that this should be a simplified example to show the case where the referred-to object is destroyed *somewhere* before being accessed via the previously stored reference. You can not solve this problem (directly).

You can stumble upon this "problem" in STL as well. For example, if you take a reference to a vector element, then insert something into the vector, pay attention that the reference (likely) became invalid as the container content may have moved somewhere else due to new memory allocation.

The only way I see to avoid this, is use of smart pointers. At least to guarantee that access to the object is safe. This will not get you access to a *new* object, should some code change the behind your back replace `(*number)[5]` with a *new* digit.

Now on to your first question: Currently, I cannot see how you intend to set a certain digit on a `Number` object. You do have an assignment operator for digit, but since `Number::operator[]` returns Digit by value, you cannot use it to set the digit.

I *assume* that my (mis)understanding is only due to an incomplete code sample. Please extend appropriately. For now, I'll assume that the `Digit`s of a `Number` are initialized in `Number`'s constructor and that your `operator[]` is only intended for access.

In general, you could just create a `const` version of said operator that returns `const Digit`. Do not use `const_cast` to remove `const` if you are not 100% sure that the object is not const. Otherwise, you will get undefined behaviour. However, it is safe to use `const_cast` to add/remove `const` to/from non-const objects. This can be useful to re-use code for `const` and non-`const` access methods. The non-`const` method can add `const`, call the `const` access method, and then safely remove `const` from the return value (well, this depends on your implementation). See Scott Meyers' "Effective C++" for more details.

That said, I have to add that I usually expect a reference to an object when calling `operator[]`, which might allow me to change the object (example: `std::vector` or `std::map`). If it is only intended for read-only access, return by const reference or by const value, not by (non-const) value. Otherwise, mistakes like

```
Number[5] = 12;
```

will happen and go unnoticed. A reader would assume that `12` is assigned to the Digit`stored in Number[5]`. In fact, it is only stored in a *copy* of said `Digit`. If `Number::operator[]` only returns `const Digit`, the compiler will catch this.

#### Edit

I see how you can return by-value but still have the original number modified. However, I still find this interface unintuitive. In *most* cases, providing operators for your class is only sensible, if it provides consistent, or even better, intuitive, behaviour. Looking at your `operator[]` declaration, I only see that it returns a `Digit` by value. Your *interface* tells me, I get a copy. There is no way to see that it internally still modifies my `Number` object.

Therefore, I think the interface will be clearer if you use getter/setter methods.

Comment: "The only way I see to avoid this, is use of smart pointers." -- Or actually learning about your containers invalidation rules and how to get along with them (in `std::vector`'s case, you'd first `reserve`) or changing to a reference-preserving container (`map`, `deque`, `list`).

Comment: @Xeo True for this specific case, however, I only picked the `vector` as an example for reference invalidation. Actually, by calling `reserve`, you _do_ make sure that your reference stays valid (as long as your don't exceed your reserved size). That was exactly my point (I did not dig into the ways _how_ you can make sure your reference stays valid).

Comment: I've expanded the source as requested.

Comment: @Xeo in the general case yes, but in my case there is no problem with extending internal structures (they are vectors, by the way). Digit holds reference to Number and index and calls appropriate method, so there's no problem with the container. Problem arises, however, when the instance of number is deleted, while user holds the reference to Digit (which, in turn, keeps reference to deleted number instance). I may forbid user to use the new operator on Number, but even that might not be enough...

Comment: @Spook This emphasises my assumption that `operator[]` is only for read-only access to a `Digit`.

Comment: @JohannesS. You mean: it should be?

Comment: @Spook No, I mean it currently is, but that I don't think it should (at least not as it is right now, see end of my answer for details)

Comment: @JohannesS. Read my question again, I've expanded the source code. Assigning the value to Digit will result in actual assigning the digit to number.